# Can I use model validation to validate HTTP headers in .Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-headers, bad-request, model-validation

I have a model validation that uses a custom header:

```
[HttpGet("")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetData([FromHeaderCustomerId, CustomerId] string customerId)
```

These 2 attributes read from header and validate the header. If the validation does not pass, I get something liket that:

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "someId",
    "errors": {
        "X-Customer-ID": [
            "The customerId field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

That works just fine, but I do have additional headers that I do not read in every request as a parameter. I would like to validate these custom headers in some simple way so that Asp.Net Core would generate 400 response the same way it does when I use model validation for a paramter.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Maybe it will helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494937/how-can-i-validate-request-headersauthorization-for-all-controller-at-a-sing

Comment: custom middleware is definitely an option

Comment: I can definitely write custom middleware and do the validation, the problem is I would like to leverage the existing model validation in there somehow to avoid writing it myself, especially the generation of response

Comment: I think there is no default validation method for custom headers in asp.net core, you need to implement it by custom methods.